# Google Analytics - Overriding Default Values

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am trying to confirm a 'pageview' is being processed properly. 
( using google real time dashboard ).

The issue is simple, If I use this call:

```
// page uri is: www.example.com/signup
ga( 'send', 'pageview' );
```

I see a matching entry at google's dashboard.

Attempting to override the title / page parameters ( according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding) ) like so:

```
ga( 'send', 'pageview', {
    'page': '/admin/logout',
    'title': "test"
} );
```

Simply produces nothing over at google's side.

Any idea what is going on?

**EDIT**

It appears that google analytics service is filtering pages that contain
the word "admin".

Removing that from the 'page' helped in my case.

Comment: If you use Chrome you could use the GA debugger extension to see if the data is being sent (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en). Plus check if there are any filters in your data view. Code looks correct.

Comment: Why would I need an extension when I can see the request under the dev tool's network tab..?

Comment: Because the extension has the data nicely formatted plus it shows the sequence in which GA commands are executed. And it shows when a call fails (and the reason why) which the network tab won't.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I appreciate the suggestion. I did try and use it but it seems  everything is running as it should..

Comment: For what it's worth, if you don't want to install the extension you can simply change the script URL from `analytics.js` to `analytics_debug.js`, more info [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's going on because your syntax is definitely correct.

FWIW, while the real time dashboard is a great way to see your hits come in, it should not be considered proof or evidence that something is or isn't working. Everything you send to Google Analytics goes through processing after it comes in, and (for a variety of reasons) a hit may be dropped from reports after showing up successfully in the real time view.

There's also always the possibility that there's a bug in the real time dashboard, and a particular hit may not show up even though it will ultimately make it into your Google Analytics reports.

A much more reliable way to see if your code is working is to take a look at the data that is actually being sent from your page. You can do this via the network inspector (in Chrome) or by using the [debug version of analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug), which logs status and error message to the console.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. The funny thing is the fact that when I only override the page title parameter, the entry shows up at the real time table.

I'll give the verbose version of the script a try nonetheless.